# Binary String to INT in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 7 bit binary data stored in a SQL Server database as `varchar`. This 7 bit binary data ultimately needs to be converted into an int. I was attempting to take this binary string and then convert to `varbinary` and then convert to integer. The cast to `varbinary` can accept a hex string, but I'm unable to find a way for this cast to accept a binary string.

Example strings:

```
0000010
0000100
0001001
```

These should convert to:

```
2
4
9
```

I could create a CLR function to call a C# function, but I was hoping to do this all in T-SQL.

Comment: just create a table with the 128 possible strings and values and look it up from there

Answer (score 2):

Convertion by hand

```
select id, sum(cast(substring(str, 7-p.pos, 1) as int) * power(2, p.pos)) val
from (
  SELECT 1 id, '0001001' str union all
  SELECT 2 id, '0001011' str
) t
cross apply (
  values 
     (0)
    ,(1)
    ,(2)
    ,(3)
    ,(4)
    ,(5)
    ,(6)
  ) p(pos)
group by id
```

Comment: Genius! Thank you!